# How to load a div on click, when the previous one has been dynamically generated from a list?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Hi there and sorry up front if this question has been asked and answered before.

Currently I have a (sort of) json file filled with content. Each item is generated to be a separate div.

On page load only the first item should be shown. After clicking on the first item, it should be hidden and the second one should be shown instead.

The current output is every div beneath the other and I am quite lost on how to get it working the way I want it to, so I hope you can help me out a bit.

json.js

```
function divlist(arr) {
  var output = '';
  var i;
//  var date_current_local = new Date();
  var date_current_milli = Date.parse(new Date());
  for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].time <= date_current_milli) {
      var date_json = new Date(arr[i].time);
      var date_json_sane = date_json.toDateString();
      output += '<div id="' + arr[i].time + '">' + date_json_sane + '<br />' + arr[i].content + '</div><br />';
    }
  }
  output += '</div>';
  document.getElementById("divlist").innerHTML = output;
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Divlist
    </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="divlist" class="divlist"></div>
    <script src="script/json.js">
      divlist();
    </script>
    <script src="script/flask.json"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

flask.json

```
divlist([
  {
    "time": 1468966500000,
    "content": "Content of Div1"
  },
  {
    "time": 1468966600000,
    "content": "Content of Div2"
  },
  {
    "time": 1468966700000,
    "content": "Content of Div3"
  }
])
```

Comment: your script is just running once at the start when the page loads and outputting everything straight away. You need to learn about javascript events, and then create a "click" event handler to listen for user clicks on your divs, and then just output the next item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of overwriting the `innerHTML` attribute on the DOM node works perfectly to replace the old content with the new content. The problem is that your `divlist()` function is iterating over the entire data array and doing something strange with times. Your verbal description of the problem does not talk about times at all.

I've renamed your function to `showDiv()`. Instead of taking the entire array, I wrote the function to take the current index to display within the target div. The function closures around the data array which I define at global scope using a variable declaration. Hence the variable (`data`) is hoisted to the top of the scope and can be closured by `showDiv()`.

The index state variable (`index`) I also define at global scope so that it can persist during the lifetime of the page.

To show the first array element content at load-time I initialize `index` to zero and call `showDiv()` on it. To provide for the advancement of the content on each click of the div, I attach a click handler to the div element using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), which, when triggered, simply increments the global `index` variable (which the handler function closures) and then calls `showDiv()` on it once again. I included a modulus operation on the increment so that it will wrap around, but you may or may not want this.

Also note that I changed your [`toDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) call to [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), which also displays the time component of the `Date` value. This helps to distinguish the `Date` values, since they all happen to have the same date.

```js
// functions
function showDiv(index) {
    // note: closures around data
    var x = data[index];
    var date_json = new Date(x.time);
    var date_json_sane = date_json.toISOString();
    var output = '<div>'+date_json_sane+'<br/>'+x.content+'</div><br/>';
    document.getElementById('divlist').innerHTML = output;
} // end showDiv()

// load JSON data
var data = [
    {
        "time": 1468966500000,
        "content": "Content of Div1"
    },
    {
        "time": 1468966600000,
        "content": "Content of Div2"
    },
    {
        "time": 1468966700000,
        "content": "Content of Div3"
    }
];

// initialize object index and display it
var index = 0;
showDiv(index);

// attach click event handler to advance index
document.getElementById('divlist').addEventListener('click',function() {
    index = (index+1)%data.length;
    showDiv(index);
}); // end divlist click handler
```

```css
#divlist {
    background-color:cyan;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Divlist
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="divlist" class="divlist"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe I should have removed 'time' from this as well, just to avoid confusion (there's actually a reason why I have it the way it is ;) ).
But this actually looks (from the code snippet that is) like I want it to, thank you very much for the solution and accompanied explanation.
I will implement this into my code tomorrow (unfortunately I'm one of those who have to work on weekends).